# AWK escape double quotes in pattern matching

Tags: awk

I am using a pattern matching as below:

```
awk -F"|" 'NR == 2 {
if (length($1) > 50) {print NR "\t" " Does not meet length requirements"}
if ($1 ~ /["&+%\\|"]/) {print NR "\t" "has an invalid character"}}' Skruggle.csv
```

The only reason to use double quotes in the pattern is to escape pipe and use it literally instead of alternation. The code is successfully able to match &,+.% and |, however, it also finds double quotes. I don't want to match double quotes in the pattern. How do I use pipe as a literal match and at the same time skip from matching double quotes in the same pattern matching regular expression?

Any inputs will be appreciated.
BigBaby608

Comment: Whatever is enclosed in `[ ]` should be treated literally and should not require double quotes, which will also be treated literally since they are inside `[  ]`. By the way trying to capture your delimiter as defined by `-F` and report your delimiter as invalid character makes no sense. Pipe will never be part of `$1`, since pipe separates `$1` from `$2`.

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou: you should probably make this an answer.

Comment: @ georgevasiliou I have tried:                           
 `  awk -F"|" 'NR == 2 {if ($1 ~ /[&+%,|]/) {print NR "\t" "has an invalid 
    character"}}' Skruggle.csv`                                                                                                                                                                                                                Every other character is found in the CSV but the pipe is not found. I am checking data that will be entered manually into  excel and then saved as a CSV. I need to make sure that the data does not include &+%,|

Comment: As i explained the pipe will NOT be found in $1 since the pipe is the delimiter that seperates fields thus is not printed.